# node app with coffeescript and gulp

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, gulp

I'm pretty new to node, but I'm trying to dive in by taking a framework that's already built ([skeleton](https://github.com/dstroot/skeleton)) and converting it to coffeescript.

So this has a config folder, with `config.js`, `passport.js`, and `utils.js` files... also, obviously, in the root, `app.js`. He's using gulp, so there's a `gulpfile.js`. I wanted to convert these files to coffeescript, and not just the user js files. Is that bad practice? I've added gulp-coffee as a devDependency, and coffee-script as a dependency.

Upon rebuilding the aforementioned files, and renaming them...

```
[12:23:40] 'coffee' errored after 61 μs
[12:23:40] Error: Invalid glob argument
  at Gulp.src (/Users/brett/Dropbox/Apps/mean_projects/skeleton/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/lib/src/index.js:17:11)

... and further down

[gulp] [nodemon] starting `coffee --debug app.coffee`
/Users/brett/Dropbox/Apps/mean_projects/skeleton/config/config.coffee: line 1, col 1, Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
/Users/brett/Dropbox/Apps/mean_projects/skeleton/config/config.coffee: line 1, col 13, Missing semicolon.
/Users/brett/Dropbox/Apps/mean_projects/skeleton/config/config.coffee: line 3, col 1, Expected an identifier and instead saw '#'.
```

That shows `config.coffee`, and there are blocks of errors for each of the files that I converted from js to coffee (app, app_cluster, gulpfile, utils, passport, etc).

Any help on the topic would be good... I've been reading quite a few articles (some that hate coffeescript) but nothing that really shows how to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

If you use gulp 3.7+, then gulpfile.coffee is supported out of the box. No need to do any extra setup.﻿

If you have to use an earlier you can bootstrap coffeescript, by just putting this in it:

```
// Note the new way of requesting CoffeeScript since 1.7.x
require('coffee-script/register');
// This bootstraps your Gulp's main file
require('./Gulpfile.coffee');
```

Then you can put you setup in gulpfile.coffee.

Is that what you meant?